# Issues reauthenticaing a user with credentials inside of react native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a react native application. I want to be able to reauthenticate a user before submitting the updated email. I am running into the issue of reautneticaing the user.

tried

```
  const saveProfile = () => {
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, 'hellohello')
    user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
      .then(() => {
        updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail.toString())
          .then(() => {
            console.log('updated email')
            setUser(auth.currentUser)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

and

```
  const saveProfile = () => {
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, 'hellohello')
    reauthenticateWithCredential(credential)
      .then(() => {
        updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail.toString())
          .then(() => {
            console.log('updated email')
            setUser(auth.currentUser)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

When i try to update the email with firebase, it says I have to `Firebase: Error (auth/requires-recent-login).`

error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'credential._getReauthenticationResolver')
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn/phone-eec7f987.js:5048:20 in _processCredentialSavingMfaContextIfNecessary
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn/phone-eec7f987.js:5212:113 in tslib.__generator$argument_1
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:144:21 in step
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:125:60 in 
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:118:17 in 
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:15 in __awaiter
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/rn/phone-eec7f987.js:5333:49 in tslib.__generator$argument_1
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:144:21 in step
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:125:60 in 
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:118:17 in 
> at node_modules/@firebase/auth/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:114:15 in __awaiter
> at src/screens/SettingsScreen.js:158:4 in saveProfile
> at src/screens/SettingsScreen.js:186:81 in TouchableOpacity.props.onPress
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:702:17 in _performTransitionSideEffects
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:639:6 in _receiveSignal
> at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Pressability/Pressability.js:520:8 in responderEventHandlers.onResponderRelease

Answer (score 1):

The `reauthenticateWithCredential()` function takes `currentUser` as first parameter. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const saveProfile = async () => {
  const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, 'hellohello')

  // auth.currentUser as first param
  await reauthenticateWithCredential(auth.currentUser, credential);

  await updateEmail(auth.currentUser, newEmail.toString())
  console.log('updated email')
  setUser(auth.currentUser)
}
```